# Prove that $\Sigma_1$ formulas are [upwards] absolute between transitive models

Tags: logic, set-theory

My attempt: let $\psi = \exists x \varphi$ be a $\Sigma_1$ formula i.e. $\varphi$ is $\Delta_0$. Suppose $M\models \psi$, hence there is $m \in M$ for which $\varphi^M[m]$ is true in $M$. Since $M \subseteq N$ then $m \in N$. Moreover, all $\Delta_0$ formulas are absolute between transitive models, hence $\varphi^N[m]$ holds in $N$, meaning $N\models \psi$. Thus $\psi$ is upwards absolute between $M$ and $N$.

I am very new to model theory (and especially models of set theory) and I have a hard time understanding how proofs here work. Does my attempt make sense? I wonder if there is an error in justifying that $\varphi^N[m]$ holds. However, since $M \subseteq N$ then I believe this to be valid.

Comment: Your argument and conclusion are valid, but the title of your question alludes as like you are asking for the wrong question, as you are asking $\Sigma_1$-formulas are (both upwards and downwards) absolute that is false.

Comment: Thank you, Hanul. To be precise, they are only upwards absolute, correct?

Comment: That's correct.